# Replace white spacing

Tags: php, html, magento

I'm needing to replace white spacing with a plus sign "+" for the code displayed below.

I'm in the process of modifying some code which generates the label and url for products displayed in my catalog. The problem I face is that my current code doesn't do the replacement. Can someone please modify the code, replacing a spacing for a plus sign "+".

```
<h5><a href="http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/catalogsearch/result/order=relevance&dir=desc&q=<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h5>
```

and will return a url something like this:

http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/catalogsearch/result/?order=relevance&dir=desc&q=potassium nitrate

However, when getName() function is used, names which have a space don't work for the generated search query. So I need to replace the space with a "+" to make the search query url work.

Thanks

Comment: Btw, the code is pretty hard to read.

Comment: I don't know how to make it a larger scroll box...How do I give it height.

Comment: I would just put some enter spaces in there.

Comment: Does something as simple as `$productName = str_replace(' ', '', $_product->getName());` work? That will take spaces out of any variable simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand your problem, you need to replace spaces by hypens in your product name. This can be achieved by replacing the following code in your href

```
...<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>...
```

with

```
...<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true)); ?>...
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following to make you code slightly nicer (although PHP/HTML soup is never a lot of fun). The first line of PHP is the one that replaces spaces with hyphen

```
<?php
     /*Get product name, stripped of HTML and spaces*/
     $productName = str_replace(' ', '-', strip_tags($_product->getName(), null, true));

     /*Assign variables rather than using same function multiple times.*/
     $productAttribute = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
     /*Concatenate the URL here for easier code fixing later.*/
     $url = 'http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/catalogsearch/result/order=relevance&dir=desc&q=' . $productName;
?>
<h5>
     <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"title="<?php echo $productName; ?>"><?php echo $productAttribute ?></a>
</h5>
```

Comment: This looks good, but I'm a Magento / PHP noob and keep getting this message when I try to insert your code.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function stripTags() in

Comment: Replace stripTags() with strip_tags(), or use the class method in your code which is $this->stripTags();

Comment: Ok now it's not displaying the concatenated text "product name". know what's wrong with the "url" variable? or how we should be connecting the 2 parts. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what the $_product->getName() and strip_tags($_product->getName(), null, true) return?

Comment: @Efficient I just tested the code above, but replacing Magento objects with simple strings and it worked as expected outputting `<h5>
     <a href="http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/catalogsearch/result/order=relevance&dir=desc&q=name-with-spaces"title="name-with-spaces">name with spaces</a>
</h5>`